# Creating Wi-Fi Hotspot on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualization, hot-spot

I read other posts here about this, and they use an Ubuntu or Linux Guest VM on a Host Machine with a WiFi Adapter or something like that, but I am confused because some of the terminal commands they use don't work, and the list of Wireless devices I get from using `sudo iwconfig` says *no wireless extensions* on all of them, like so:

*lo ⁭ ⁭ ⁭ ⁭⁭ ⁭ ⁭ ⁭ no wireless extensions.*

*enp0s3⁭ ⁭ ⁭ ⁭ ⁭no wireless extensions.*

And the Ubuntu Guest VM I am using seems to list the connection as "Wired Connection", and the Host Machine has a Wi-Fi USB in it for Internet connection.

So, how exactly would you make a Wi-Fi Mobile Hotspot connection on an Ubuntu VM?

Comment: Add the wifi adapter to the vm usb first

Comment: If the host is Ubuntu, there is no need to use a VM when creating a hotspot 

Comment: @matigo The host is Windows, the guest is Ubuntu

Comment: If you already pay for Windows, do it in Windows and ask Microsoft support. Yes, I know, this is not a polite answer (and I am sorry for that by writing this), but this is my opinion.

Comment: @Marco I want to make a hotspot without a password. I don't think the hotspot settings included with Windows lets you do that, cuz I just tried it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1457728/create-hotspot-without-password

Comment: @Marco that just gives me an error when I run "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" in cmd. Yes I am using administrator mode. Yes it still gives the error as I tried it again.